# Unable to compile out of the box Qt Gui App in the Visual Studio extension C++

Tags: visual-studio, c++, qt

I was banging my hand against this wall, attempting to install the qt Visual studio tools, both VS and the Qt extension are the latest 2019 version, with the Qt version 5.13.0:

[image]

Basically after I've tried creating a Qt Gui Application, the same would always occur, fail to compile with the same errors:

[image]

Which traces back to line 74 in qtrcc.targets, trying to run other types of Qt project all fail outside of creating a Qt Console App.

[image]

I already have Qt Creator working just fine, I have attempted to reinstall VS and the corresponding Extension to the 2017 version, with the same error occuring, I have attempted to run as Admin,

Heres my Qt Options if that might help decipher the problem:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Did you check the build output? It probably contains vital information. /edit: Ah wait, with `2> nul` you probably won’t see any error messages. Just try running the command yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the help, the only information in the build output is that it failed to compile, with the following error that I already linked in the OP: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJEkj.png

Comment: Have you configured your solution, and made it aware of the fact, your Visual C++ 2017 installation is installed on that specific drive?  I will be honest I am not entirely sure what your question is.